# Replacing 'StepIt' from a ProgressBar to a cxProgressBar

Tags: delphi, progress-bar, devexpress

I've just replaced my common progress bar with a cxProgressBar, I noticed, however, that it does not have the method 'StepIt'.

I replaced StepIt with this:

```
progressbar1.Position := progressbar1.Position+1;
```

I do not think it to be the best choice since the Progress takes much slower than StepIt.

To set the maximum value I get a total counts of fields on the sql table that it's going to be converted into local cache.

I have never tried anything other than the common ProgressBar, that's why I came across this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like the only *problem* mentioned here is that your new code is slower, but you haven't *described* that problem at all. Why is it slower? How have you measured? How are you using this new code compared to what it was with the original VCL control? If performance isn't the problem, then what is? What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: I would say the problem here is that OP steps the progress in a timer event and because of increment by constant 1 (not the step value) it takes a long time. @Rosenberg - if the cxProgressBar responds to the [PBM_STEPIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message (as common progress bars do), you can use `ProgressBar1.Perform(Handle, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);` and you'll get the fastest way to step.

Comment: My question, Rob, was how to replace 'StepIt', because of the clear lack of it in this particular progressbar. I tested it by putting it side by side and seeing how fast it'd load, and apparently my code took three time as long as the common progressbar, so, clearly it's either an issue with the code or a lack thereof. By investigating further I found that step was using a variable, which I proceeded to replace the +1 with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the online help: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TProgressBar.StepIt

> Advances Position by the amount specified in the Step property.
>
> Call the StepIt method to increase the value of Position by the value of the Step property. If Step represents the size of one logical step in the process tracked by the progress bar, call Step after each logical step is completed.

The following code should do the trick.

```
procedure MyStepIt(NrOfSteps);
var
  Step: integer;
begin
  Step:= Max(1,(ProgressBar1.Max - ProgressBar1.Min) div NrOfSteps);
  ProgressBar1.Position:= Min(ProgressBar1.Max, ProgressBar1.Position + Step);
end;
```

Comment: With `Min = 0`, `Max = 10` and `NrOfSteps = 20` you'd get `Step = 0`.

Comment: Yeah, this works, going to subclass the ProgressBar component and implement it as a property. Thanks.